# MalformedJsonException: Unexpected value at line 1 column 343 path $.nickname

Tags: java, android

[image]

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<Subscriber>() {}.getType();

Subscriber data = new Gson().fromJson(response.body().get("data").toString().trim(), listType);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(data);
editor.putString("subscriber", json);
editor.apply();
```

Comment: Please post you JSON

Comment: Please post json string you are getting in response

Comment: it says that there is something wrong with your JSON.

Comment: Please click enter image description here

Comment: @Rohit5k2 please Help me

Comment: Please post code of Subscriber

Comment: @Rohit5k2 subscriber model class code?